# Does File::Basename::dirname always return the parent or root directory when the argument is an absolute pathname?

Tags: perl, path, dirname

Are there situations where this subroutine - called with a valid path which is not the root directory - does not return the parent directory?

```
use Cwd qw( realpath );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

sub parent_dir {
    my $dir = realpath shift;
    return dirname $dir;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`File::Basename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aBasename) documentation mentions this caveat:

> **`dirname`**
>
> This function is provided for compatibility with the Unix shell
>   command `dirname(1)` and has inherited some of its quirks. In spite of
>   its name it does ***NOT*** always return the directory name as you
>   might expect. To be safe, if you want the directory name of a path use
>   `fileparse()`.

A few examples are presented which makes this clear:

```
+----------------+-----------+---------------+
| Test Path      | dirname() | fileparse()   |
+----------------+-----------+---------------+
| /foo/bar/baz   | /foo/bar  | /foo/bar/     |  # dirname() works as expected
+----------------+-----------+---------------+
| /foo/bar/baz/  | /foo/bar  | /foo/bar/baz/ |  # Should have included baz here
+----------------+-----------+---------------+
| foo/           | .         | foo/          |  # fileparse() wins again
+----------------+-----------+---------------+
```

---

If absolute paths for simple directories and filepaths (without trailing slashes) are provided, the path is similar to the first test, which means that the parent directory is always returned.

Comment: Changed the title of my question because it didn't match the posted text.